# Extract tibble_df and text message from activitylog object

Tags: r, daqapo

I have the code below

```
library(bupar)
library(daqapo)
hospital<-hospital
hospital %>%
  rename(start = start_ts,
         complete = complete_ts) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  convert_timestamps(c("start","complete"), format = dmy_hms) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  activitylog(case_id = "patient_visit_nr",
              activity_id = "activity",
              resource_id = "originator",
              timestamps = c("start", "complete")) -> hospital
hospital %>%
  detect_time_anomalies()
```

which gives

```
*** OUTPUT ***
For 5 rows in the activity log (9.43%), an anomaly is detected.
The anomalies are spread over the activities as follows:
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  activity      type                  n
  <chr>         <chr>             <int>
1 Registration  negative duration     3
2 Clinical exam zero duration         1
3 Trage         negative duration     1
Anomalies are found in the following rows:
# Log of 10 events consisting of:
3 traces 
3 cases 
5 instances of 3 activities 
5 resources 
Events occurred from 2017-11-21 11:22:16 until 2017-11-21 19:00:00 
 
# Variables were mapped as follows:
Case identifier:        patient_visit_nr 
Activity identifier:        activity 
Resource identifier:        originator 
Timestamps:     start, complete 

# A tibble: 5 × 10
  patient_visit_nr activity      originator start               complete            triagecode specialization .order durat…¹ type 
             <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      <dttm>              <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>           <int>   <dbl> <chr>
1              518 Registration  Clerk 12   2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 1  -23    nega…
2              518 Registration  Clerk 6    2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 2  -23    nega…
3              518 Registration  Clerk 9    2017-11-21 11:45:16 2017-11-21 11:22:16          4 PED                 3  -23    nega…
4              520 Trage         Nurse 17   2017-11-21 13:43:16 2017-11-21 13:39:00          5 URG                 4   -4.27 nega…
5              528 Clinical exam Doctor 1   2017-11-21 19:00:00 2017-11-21 19:00:00          3 TRAU                5    0    zero…
# … with abbreviated variable name ¹​duration
```

from this output I would like to extract the text message

```
For 5 rows in the activity log (9.43%), an anomaly is detected.
The anomalies are spread over the activities as follows:
```

and also in another object the tibble

```
activity      type                  n
  <chr>         <chr>             <int>
1 Registration  negative duration     3
2 Clinical exam zero duration         1
3 Trage         negative duration     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are trying to obtain is a `message`, and though it is possible to capture a message, it's not that straightforward. You can easily generate it by emulating a couple of lines within the function though.

If you store the result of `detect_time_anomalies`:

```r
anomalies <- hospital %>% detect_time_anomalies()
```

Then you can generate the message like this:

```r
paste0("For ", nrow(anomalies), " rows in the activity log (", 
       round(nrow(anomalies)/nrow(hospital) * 100, 2), 
       "%), an anomaly is detected.")
#> [1] "For 5 rows in the activity log (9.43%), an anomaly is detected."
```

Similarly, you can obtain the output table like this:

```r
anomalies %>%
  group_by(activity, type) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   activity      type                  n
#>   <chr>         <chr>             <int>
#> 1 Registration  negative duration     3
#> 2 Clinical exam zero duration         1
#> 3 Trage         negative duration     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks a similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792097/extract-dataframes-from-activity-log-object